# CSS hover image animate a sibling element

Tags: css

I want to hover over a image to animate and display a block of text using CSS. The problem is that I can only seem to animate child elements.

```
<div id="does-not-work">
  <p>DOES NOT WORK</p>
  <p>Hover over the image</p>
  <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png"/>
  <p class="show-bubble">Should display this text</p>
</div>

#does-not-work img:hover .show-bubble{
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

My expectation is that I hover over the img element inside the `#does-not-work` div and it shoud change the max height of `.show-bubble`. But it doesn't.

Using a html construction like this does work though:

```
<div id="does-work">
  <p>DOES WORK</p>
  <p>Hover over the image</p>
  <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-W__wiaHUjwI/Vt3Grd8df0I/AAAAAAAAA78/7xqUNj8ujtY/s1600/image02.png"/>
  <p class="show-bubble">Should display this text</p>
</div>

#does-work:hover .show-bubble{
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

This is because the hover is now on the parent element of the block I want to show. The problem is that I only want to trigger the animate effect when a user hovers over the image, and not the whole block

https://plnkr.co/edit/4qbwdGkW9l5P6WvvtTsP?p=preview

Comment: Remove this code
#does-not-work img:hover .show-bubble{
  max-height: 200px;
}

#does-work:hover .show-bubble{
  max-height: 200px;
}

And add this

#does-not-work img:hover ~ .show-bubble{
  max-height: 200px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have `.hover` for parent element and `img` tag together. So both the hover triggers at same time

```
Remove this code
#does-not-work img:hover .show-bubble{
  max-height: 200px;
}

#does-work:hover .show-bubble{
  max-height: 200px;
}

And add this code

#does-not-work img:hover ~ .show-bubble{
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#does-not-work img:hover + .show-bubble{
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

Or

```
#does-not-work img:hover ~ .show-bubble{
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make the hover work you need to change your code to the following:

```
#does-not-work img:hover + .show-bubble{
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

and the hover will fire when you hover over the image as opposed to the div.

The plus (+) operator in CSS is the adjacent sibling selector. It will select the element after the image which is what you want.